# Eclipse - Refresh Plugin components

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I worked around the way to change the locale of the plugin. But there is a couple of components that need to be refreshed (if they are visible) such as custom Views (org.eclipse.ui.views) or Menu, in order to avoid restart Eclipse. Please I need your help.

Comment: I don't try to update the language of whole app, just my custom plugin components. 2 Reference that helped me a lot:
MENU -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202197/change-menu-items-programmatically-from-eclipse-plugin
VIEW -> http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t60857.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The platform doesn't have a way to switch locales while running.  The `IExtensionRegistry` picked a locale while loading the extensions for the views, and the only general way to update them is to restart.

The `org.eclipse.core.runtime.IExtensionRegistry` had new multi-language support added (maybe in 3.7.0?) but the framework doesn't use it at this time.

EDIT: restart

To restart your eclipse with a new locale you need to change the command line (update the **-nl** flag), save it in the system property `eclipse.exitdata`, and exit your `IApplication` with `org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplication.EXIT_RELAUNCH`.  See `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.actions.OpenWorkspaceAction` for an example of how this is used.

Comment: Can you tell me how to set the language (locale) and restart eclipse  automatically?

Comment: you can't restart the IDE until it finishes coming up.  It's not an RCP app.