# How do you get the Eclipse menubar to update on demand?

Tags: eclipse, menu, eclipse-plugin, refresh

I'm working on a plugin aiming to hide a swathe of menu contributions, then slowly reintroduce them to the UI according to how confident/experienced the user is, with help and introductory information given to the user at each step. So far I can happily hide menu contributions using activities. Getting them back has proved to be slightly more difficult, however.

I have menu contributions being hidden and shown via activities, but the problem I've run in to is that the menu isn't instantly updating to reflect the activites. When my provided variable is changed, the activities *are* being started/stopped appropriately, but the menu doesn't immediately change. That is, until you change view or perspective- actions which cause the menu to be refreshed.

I've tried calling refresh() on the MenuManager, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202197/change-menu-items-programmatically-from-eclipse-plugin), to no avail.

Obviously my expression is being evaluated immediately, but how can I get the menu itself to update/refresh immediately?
Thanks!

---

It turns out there were issues with fireSourceChanged().

Calling: `fireSourceChanged(int sourcePriority, Map sourceValuesByName)` doesn't work for me.

But calling `fireSourceChanged(int sourcePriority, String sourceName, Object sourceValue)` does work.

I *really* don't know why that is - could be an Eclipse bug??