# How to rename the eclipse plugin menu programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am developing an eclipse plugin.I have given my menu,sub menu names and plugin id  in **plugin.xml**.

I want to dynamically rename my plugin id as well my menu and sub menu name.I came across this  [SOF link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202197/change-menu-items-programmatically-from-eclipse-plugin).I am using the below code.

```
     MenuManager menuManager = ((WorkbenchWindow)window).getMenuManager();

     Menu menu = menuManager.getMenu();

     String itemId = "plugin_menu_id";

     IContributionItem item = menuManager.find(itemId);

     System.out.println("item.getId() --> " + item.getId());
     //gives the plugin_menu_id      

     System.out.println( "menu.getItemCount() ==> "+ menu.getItemCount());
     //gives no of menus in eclipse
```

But unfortunately **I am unable to find an option to rename the menu from IContributionItem**.
So is there any other way to modify things in eclipse plugin?

Comment: `WorkbenchWindow` is an **internal** class, you are violating the [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html) by using it.

Comment: oh,I am not aware of it.So what can be done.is there any other alternatives?

Comment: I am not aware of an alternative. In any case a contribution item doesn't have a name - contribution items usually add one or more menu items directly to the menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a temporary solution .Instead of using a MenuManager,I created a dynamic menu using Actions Framework instead of Command Framework though the former is deprecated.

So each time , I create a Menu,I am able to change the Menu name,icon etc.

I am searching for an equivalent in the Command Framework and will post as soon as I found that.